# create a button and set its class using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-manipulation

i am  trying to create  a to-do list in JavaScript where list is created dynamically on submitting inputs.What i want is list of task and a delete button besides them.All is done except that i am unable to add classes to button using javascript.

Here is my code..

```
<button id="add" onclick="takeInput()">Add new task</button>

<script>
function takeInput()
{
  var task=prompt("Enter the new to do work");
  if(task!=null)
  {
    var list=document.createElement("li");
    var btn=document.createElement("button");
    var data=document.createTextNode(person);
    var btndata=document.createTextNode("delete");
    list.appendChild(data);
    btn.appendChild(btndata);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(list);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(btn);

  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can add a class to your dynamically created button like this:

```
....
var btn=document.createElement("button");
btn.className = "YourClass"; 
//OR
btn.className += " YourClass" //If you want to add to existing classes
....
```

Answer (score 2):

To add class to any html element you can use.

```
element.className += " newClass";
```

This will preserve previous classes and add new class.

In you case it would be like (if you want to add class to you newly created button)

```
btn.className += " newClass";
```

if you don't want the previous class.(in your case there is none)

btn.className = " newClass";

Answer (score 0):

You can use `classList.Add`
Here's a sample:

```
btn0.classList.add('btn');
btn0.classList.add('btn-sm');
btn0.classList.add('btn-primary');
```